# GCP Kubernetes Nodes update with Internal Private Nameservers

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, dns, google-kubernetes-engine, nameservers

We have a docker image repository on GitLab which is hosted on the internal network ( repo.mycomapanydomain.io).

My K8 deployment is failing with Name not resolved error for repo.mycomapanydomain.io

I tried updating the kube-dns config as below. But I still have the same error.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
 stubDomains: |
   {“mycomapanydomain”: [“10.131.0.4”]}
 upstreamNameservers: |
   [“10.131.0.4”]
```

How can I make my resolv.conf to have the Internal nameservers by default or K8 to resolve with my internal  DNS IPs?

Comment: Hello, could you please clarify if the internal network that you are referencing (`repo.mycomapanydomain.io`) is within `GCP` or is it your own on premise one? Also are you running `GKE` or you've configured Kubernetes on `VM`'s by yourself? By default you can communicate with the `VM`'s by their names (you could contact your gitlab docker repository by the `VM` name if it's GCP resource). Also, as a workaround please consider using [Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry)

Comment: I am using GKE here.

Comment: repo.mycomapanydomain.io is with the GCP hosted on a VM. I am able to access repo.mycomapanydomain.io IP from the GKE nodes but unable to resolve it until I manually change the resolv.conf IPs in the GKE nodes.  So the solution I am looking for here is to update my resolve.conf IPs automatically or K8 to use my nameserver IPs to resolv all the DNS queries.

Comment: We hosted DNS server in GCP VM's using powerdns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing `/etc/resolv.conf` either manually or automatically is discouraged as for:

> #### Internal DNS and resolv.conf
>
> By default, most Linux distributions store DHCP information in [`resolv.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html). Compute Engine instances are configured to renew DHCP leases every 24 hours. For instances that are enabled for zonal DNS, the DHCP lease expires every hour. **DHCP renewal overwrites this file, undoing any changes that you might have made.** Instances using [zonal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#zonal-dns) have both zonal and global entries in the `resolv.conf` file.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Compute: Docs: Internal DNS: resolv.conf](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#resolv.conf)*

Also:

> **Modifications on the boot disk of a node VM do not persist across node re-creations**. Nodes are re-created during [manual upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster#upgrade_nodes), [auto-upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-upgrades), [auto-repair](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair), and [auto-scaling](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler). In addition, nodes are re-created when you enable a feature that requires node re-creation, such as [GKE sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/sandbox-pods), [intranode visibility](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/intranode-visibility), and [shielded nodes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/shielded-gke-nodes).
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Node images: Modifications](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#modifications)*

---

As for:

> How can I make my `resolv.conf` to have the Internal nameservers by default or K8 to resolve with my internal DNS IPs?

From the `GCP` and `GKE` perspective, you can use the [Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns) to configure your `DNS` resolution in either way that:

- your whole `DOMAIN` is residing in `GCP` infrastructure (and you specify all the records).
- your `DOMAIN` queries are forwarded to the DNS server of your choosing.

You can create your `DNS` zone by following:

- `GCP Cloud Console` (Web UI) -> `Network Services` -> `Cloud DNS` -> `Create zone`:

Assuming that you want to forward your `DNS` queries to your internal `DNS` server residing in `GCP` your configuration should look similar to the one below:

[image: DNS]

> A side note!
>
> 1. Remember to follow the "Destination DNS Servers" steps to allow the `DNS` queries to your `DNS` server.
> 2. Put the internal IP address of your `DNS` server where the black rectangle is placed.

After that your `GKE` cluster should be able to resolve the `DNS` queries of your `DOMAIN.NAME`.

---

#### Additional resources:

I found an article that shows how you can create a `DNS` forwarding for your `GCP` instances:

- *[Medium.com: Faun: DNS forwarding zone and dns policy in GCP](https://medium.com/faun/dns-forwarding-zone-forwarding-and-dns-policy-in-gcp-640a34b15bca)*